# Select2 ajax not working in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 in rails with gem rails-select2, currently using 4.0.3 version.

I can't manage to make the ajax version of select2 working, the static version where I set the data as an array is working while the ajax version it's not.

I'm not getting any error and no ajax calls on the backend.

The select appear empty with the select2 style and while I type it does not do anything.

Is there a way to debug or understand where the problem is?

I'm using the following example code:

On the view:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width:100%">
<option value="3620194" selected="selected">Select a value......</option>
</select>
```

On the javascript:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
      // scrolling can be used
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }

});
```

This is what I got:
[image]

No error on javascript console and everything is working if I use array data (so I guess there is no problem with the select2 import).

I need to find a way to better debug the problem to properly understand where the issue is lying.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why the example does not work but maybe this snippet will work for you to implement `select2` in `rails`.
I used `gem 'select2-rails', '4.0.3'` and `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'`

> Add this in a .js file and change `html selector` and `url` option

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  if ($(".select-vehicle")) {
    $(".select-vehicle").select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      allowClear: true,
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      dataType: 'json',
      ajax: {
        url: '/admin/vehicles/search',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
          return { vin: params.term }
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          return {
            results: $.map(data, function(value, index){
              return {id: value.id, text: value.vin};
            })
          };
          cache: true
        }
      }
    });
  }
})
```

> This is a method to search a vehicle in VehicleController

```
  def search
    if params[:vin].present?
      vehicles = Vehicle.where("vin LIKE ?", "%#{params[:vin]}%")
      render json: vehicles.map{|v| v.serializable_hash(only: [:id, :vin]) }
    else
      render json: []
    end
  end
```

This is a simple implementation of select2, tell me if it was useful.

Comment: It was extremely useful. I had the exact same problem as OP and it solved it.

Comment: It worked for me on 2023

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem with cross-domain request, you should look into browser console.